# Unknown problem with connection to Airflow Database, server closed connection unexpectedly, GCP Cloud Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I have daily ingest pipeline as production runs on Cloud Composer, the code is unchanged for a while. One day there is one error that raised from database_health.py that raised "server closed connection unexpectedly"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RM2Q.png)

at the same moment after that, in Log Explorer their are following errors from "airflow-scheduler" and "airflow-worker" that have the same errors text as above like "server closed connection unexpectedly"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZWh4.png)

I want to know how to deal with this issue, it maybe happen occasionally but the customer are really concern with this problem.

Sincerely

Chanan

How to solved the problem.

Comment: Which Airflow/Compoer do you use, there is existing similar issue for some Airflow versions: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/234362247?pli=1